# Why does this piece of code make text center align?

Tags: java

I am doing some Android programming for a receipt printer from Star Micronics. In the sample code it provides, there is a line I do not quite understand. I am puzzled by the fact that it is somewhat linking to assembly language or some sort of machine specific instructions.

```
ArrayList<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();
Byte[] tempList;

// Alignment (center)                   
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Byte[]{0x1b, 0x1d, 0x61, 0x01}));
```

Can someone tell me how that line achieves the center alignment?

Comment: Seems to be really specific to the application.  I couldn't tell you unless I cracked open the application and found the line that it was using there.

Comment: And to add to the comment made by @Makoto, it's not machine language. It's a `byte[]` in which they leveraged hexadecimal values to fill (e.g. the byte `00` can be represented as `0x0`).

Comment: More information about the Star Micronics is needed.  Maybe you can get the spec sheet for the printer.  The code you have shown simply populates an array of bytes.  At some point that array must be sent to the printer. (we don't have that code)  The printer documentation will tell you what the commands are. Somewhere in the docs it will explain the command format and you'll be able to understand why 0x1b, 0x1d, 0x61, 0x01 means "center".

Comment: This might help: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/comemu_starline_pm.pdf

Comment: What model printer is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost surely a command sequence that is sent to the printer. The exact meaning depends on the printer model, but the byte values correspond to the following character sequence:

```
<ESC><GS>a<01>
```

If this were, say, a TSP200 series printer, then according to [the programmer's manual](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/tsp200pm.pdf) (page 58) it corresponds to the function "Enable/disable automatic status transmission". Since you say that the effect is center alignment, I'm guessing it's simply a different printer model. Just check the escape sequences in the appropriate programmers manual.

Comment: Thank you guys. The link wquist and Ted Hopp provided are very helpful.